# Better way of writing this regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

Some string:

```
s = 'some text some text date may 04 at 05 AM some text some text'
```

I've written the regex to extract date from the above like below:

```
m = re.search(r'date ([a-z]{3} [0-9]{2}) at ([0-9]{2}) ([P][M])|date ([a-z]{3} [0-9]{2}) at ([0-9]{2}) ([A][M])', s)
```

Is it possible to write this regex in some shorter way or can '|' character be used in a better way than this? Because the above regexps are only different at 'AM' and 'PM' part. I just don't feel right using this regex.

Comment: 1st thaught... `re.search(r'date ([a-z]{3} [0-9]{2}) at ([0-9]{2}) ([A|P][M]))', s)

Comment: @BarunSharma: It is such a common mistake to use `|` inside a character class. `[A|P]` matches `A`, `|` or `P`.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thanks. Please ignore my comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
date ([a-z]{3} \d{2}) at (\d{2}) ([PA]M)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zU9gU4/3)

Compare your 2 alternatives:

```
date ([a-z]{3} [0-9]{2}) at ([0-9]{2}) ([P][M])
date ([a-z]{3} [0-9]{2}) at ([0-9]{2}) ([A][M])
```

Note how similar they are. We need to only add 1 alternative for `PM` or `AM`. It can be done by using a character class `[PA]` that will match either `P` or `A`.

Instead of `[0-9]`, you can use *shorthand* class `\d` (it is a bit shorter :), and do not forget to declare the regex as a raw string with `r'...'`).

Note I would use a case-insensitive flag `re.I` with this pattern (the pattern will match both `pm` and `PM` then).